# can't update from 16.04

Tags: updates, policykit, crouton

I haven't had much help in the reddit/crouton forums so I thought i'd try here. I'm trying to upgrade my ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and it is saying I do not have the proper permissions. the same thing came up when I try running Ubuntu software center so I found out a way I could get it started by typing gksudo software-center. but now when I go to software updater and it says there is an update, I can't install it because it is saying i don't have the right permissions.
In terminal it will say terminated with exit status 1. and when i try to click upgrade anyway, nothing happens but in the background of crouton this is the output I get:

```
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Dbusmenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Dbusmenu', '0.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UnitySupport.py:29: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Dbusmenu, Unity
WARNING:root:estimate_kernel_initrd_size_in_boot() returned '0' for kernel?
WARNING:root:estimate_kernel_initrd_size_in_boot() returned '0' for initrd?

(update-manager:30159): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:27:35: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:30159): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:40:48: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:30159): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:48:46: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:30159): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:59:58: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:30159): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:70:46: Junk at end of value

(update-manager:30159): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:81:58: Junk at end of value
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

I have also read that I need to enable polkit when system starts but that is already enabled on startup.

This is another error i get when trying to update:

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.111'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache
```

dang i should have waited. im use to asking questions on reddit where it takes several hours to get a response but i ended up deleted xenial and just doing a fresh install of bionic and MOST of it works. i do have another problem but i wont post it here, i'll make another thread so it doesn't get confusing. but other than that i guess this question can be deleted or closed or whatever needs to be done since its 'kinda' solved.

Comment: Did you play woth your python?

Comment: You should include the commands used. "because it is saying i don't have the right permissions" Now you will get questions like "did you use sudo?".